# Android Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parent, android-context

Is there any way to get the parent activity instance for activities that are not embedded, the same way as for TabBar Activities you can use `getParent()`? Is there a method or a way to do the same for regular activities, started with a regular intent? I need to get the context, so I can pass it forward.

Comment: Why not use the application context ?

Comment: Didn't know about that. I looked it up and used this method. Thank you!:D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the parent activity

There is no concept of "parent activities" in Android, except in the now-deprecated `ActivityGroup`.

> I need to get the context, so I can pass it forward.

First, each `Activity` is a `Context`. Second, passing `Contexts` around between component is a recipe for memory leaks. Please solve whatever problem you think you have in some other way.